# No one speaking about Cryptowall Ramsonware that use Tor network to connect to the hidden malicious servers?

Tags: malware

Apparently, Cryptowall Ramsonware uses Tor network to connect to the hidden malicious servers. I believe folks should care about this matter!

Or it is only necessary that the Tor network works in order to reach file sharing and torrent websites blocked by ISP company?

This is a serious question .. Could anybody explain what should be/could be done about this issue?

This is a serious concern and question as far as I am concerned.

Comment: There is a post on Tor blog: Tor misused by criminals. On 31c3,  arma said something like "f*ck them". It's a malware and Tor is not an AV software.

Comment: nice, i searched before posting my question, but didn't found nothing

Answer (score 2):

Folks do care about this matter. [This is the 31C3 talk that @user66466 refers to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRrFWwA-47U) (33 minutes in).

> Or it is only necessary that the Tor network works in order to reach file sharing and torrent websites blocked by ISP company?

I'm not sure what you're asking, but it is impossible to create an anonymizing network that identifies and filters the bad from the good traffic. Anyone can use the network to transmit any data they want.

> Could anybody explain what should be/could be done about this issue?

Since *the issue* is that people get their computers infected with malware, what should be done about it is mostly education. On how to prevent it, how to detect it, how to minimize the damage.

Comment: That's right, and about abuse of things, Cryptowall use the Tor2Web proxy to start the connection with the C&C Servers to gain the RSA Key, after, the user to pay need to install The TOR Client.

Comment: I wrote this as a System Administrator, not on how to avoid being infected .. solutions are obvious, but on blocking the process of the virus (the encryption of files) in question .. having seen how the virus works..